# AbortProcessingException leaves stack trace in server log, how to disable this?

Tags: jsf, exception, logging, jsf-2, actionlistener

There is a `commandButton` on a page that asynchronously invokes some service, and when user clicks a button I want to verify service availability by checking special config from database. This config can be updated every minute. So if the service is not available, `action` of `commandButton` should not be executed.

So, as per [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/3909382#3909382), I'm checking service availability in `actionListener` and throw `AbortProcessingException` in case service is not available. So `action` will be skipped.

This works fine, but it leaves a stack trace in server's log. I don't want such behavior. Is it possible to handle the exception in such way that this will not leave mark in server logs, just like when `ValidatorException` is thrown? I'm using OmniFaces `FullAjaxExceptionHandler`, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can suppress the logging with a custom exception handler. As you're currently using [OmniFaces `FullAjaxExceptionHandler`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler), you'd better extend it. In the `handle()` method, check if there's an exception and if it's an instance of `AbortProcessingException`. If so, then just ignore it and return directly from the exception handler.

```
public class YourExceptionHandler extends FullAjaxExceptionHandler {

    public YourExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler wrapped) {
        super(wrapped);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle() throws FacesException {
        Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> events = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator();

        if (events.hasNext() && events.next().getContext().getException() instanceof AbortProcessingException) {
            return; // Ignore (and don't log).
        }

        super.handle(); // Continue to FullAjaxExceptionHandler.
    }

}
```

Create a factory around it:

```
public class YourExceptionHandlerFactory extends ExceptionHandlerFactory {

    private ExceptionHandlerFactory wrapped;

    public YourExceptionHandlerFactory(ExceptionHandlerFactory wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getExceptionHandler() {
        return new YourExceptionHandler(getWrapped().getExceptionHandler());
    }

    @Override
    public ExceptionHandlerFactory getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

}
```

In order to get this to run, register it as factory in `faces-config.xml` the usual way, replacing the `FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory`:

```xml
<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>com.example.YourExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```